# Track custom video events from ooyala player version 3 in omniture

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, ooyala

As part of a test implementation I have to track the videos played through omniture milestone tracking. The player is ooyala version 3. I am able to get the code where alert is print once the video is played for 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% of the total video length. 
Question is how can i bind these with events in omniture. I did some implementation but i guess, the reports are coming blank for these custom events.
The logic is once the video reaches 25% mark, event1 should be fired, if 50% mark, event2 should be fired and so on. and these custom events in omniture should return the counts so that i will know how many times these events have been fired... Any help please.

code -

```
<script>
var s=s_gi("Report Suite ID")
var mplayer, mesb, dur, title, events, event7, event8, event9, event10;
OO.ready(function() {
var lastTriggerPos;
mplayer = OO.Player.create('ooyalaplayer','player ID');
mplayer.mb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYBACK_READY, 'example',  
function(eventName) {
title = mplayer.getCurrentItemTitle();
var vData = mplayer.getItem();
dur = parseInt(vData.time);
});
mplayer.mb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYHEAD_TIME_CHANGED, 'example', 
function(eventName) 
{
phPos = parseInt(mplayer.getPlayheadTime());
if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 0.25)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos)
{
lastTriggerPos = phPos;
s.events=event7
} 
else if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 0.50)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) 
{
  lastTriggerPos = phPos;
  s.events=event8;

} 
else if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 0.75)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) 
{
  lastTriggerPos = phPos;
  s.events=event9;

} else if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 1)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) 
{
  lastTriggerPos = phPos;
   s.events=event10;
}
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)
});});
</script>
```

Comment: at face value the first thing I see wrong is your events should be wrapped in quotes, e.g. `s.events="event7";`

Comment: ok thanx.. your solution worked for me...